# Root Path in R XML

Tags: xml, r, xpath

When you specify XML node paths for instance : `//tr[@class='party-rep']`

and do

```
getNodeSet(rootsChild, //tr[@class='party-rep'])
```

Does this function still search from the root of the tree looking for a tr div with class "party-rep" or since we specified rootsChild as the doc, it will search starting from rootsChild and all its children and ignore the actual root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you all the `<tr class='party-rep'>` in your xml document :

```
getNodeSet(rootsChild, "//tr[@class='party-rep']")
```

If you want all the `<tr class='party-rep'>` elements which are children of the `rootsChild` element, you have to add a point in front of your xpath expression :

```
getNodeSet(rootsChild, ".//tr[@class='party-rep']")
```

Here is an example :

```
R> xml <- "<root><a><td>foo</td></a><b><td>bar</td></b></root>"
R> doc <- xmlParse(xml)
R> doc
# <?xml version="1.0"?>
# <root>
#   <a>
#     <td>foo</td>
#   </a>
#   <b>
#     <td>bar</td>
#   </b>
# </root>

R> a <- getNodeSet(doc, '//a')[[1]]
R> getNodeSet(a, '//td')
# [[1]]
# <td>foo</td> 
# 
# [[2]]
# <td>bar</td> 
# 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "XMLNodeSet"

R> getNodeSet(a, './/td')
# [[1]]
# <td>foo</td> 
# 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

Comment: Your example suggests (opposite of your description) that adding "." limits the retrieval to the first node.

Comment: @DWin The `.` limits the retrieval to the children of the node given to `getNodeSet`. Do you mean I should add several `<td>` elements to the `<a>` node to make the example more explicit ?